# Conflicting AutoLayout Constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Running my code I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x7a09e6a0 UITableView:0x7c1d4400.contentHeight{id: 178} == -5.000000>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x7a09e6a0 UITableView:0x7c1d4400.contentHeight{id: 178} == -5.000000>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**How do I find the source of this problem?**

Comment: Do you understand how constraints are used to determine the font size of a scroll view?

Comment: Have you set the `contentSize` and/or `contentInset` of a view which inherits from `UIScrollView`? It looks you've managed to cause a negative height. Try setting a breakpoint for All Exceptions - Objective-C to find out where you did something to cause a negative height.

Answer (score 0):

You just add and extra constraint to your tableview, remove the constraint you don't need to add your tableview. It shows the problem in your  **contentHeight**. Just remove the contentHeight and add proper constraint there.

Comment: That constraint clearly comes from UIKit, because its class is `_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint` which is not something any constraint he added himself would be.